# How to get value of {% url '...' %} programatically?

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I would like to include the url of my DRF endpoint in the `extra_context=` field of my TemplateView so that I can pass it into my JS application in my template. I currently have it in my template, but it's just more convenient to store all the urls in the urls.py file.

```
path('channel_bar', TemplateView.as_view(
             template_name='sales/bar_graph.html'
             extra_context={'dataUrl': reverse_lookup_drf_url('url-name')}
         ),
         name='sales.channel.bar'),
```

and I don't know the Django name of the function `reverse_lookup_drf_url(...)`

Tried searching "reverse lookup of template url tag programmatically" and a few permutations of it but didn't get any results. Anyone know the answer? I'm sure it's simple, just can't get a Google result.

Comment: There's no special / different function w.r.t. DRF for that, you want to be using `reverse_lazy` (part of Django itself), although I don't know why you even want to do this, since you are rendering a template anyway the `url` tag would be enough for you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work with [**`reverse_lazy(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse-lazy) in this case:

```
from django.urls import reverse_lazy

path('channel_bar', TemplateView.as_view(
    template_name='sales/bar_graph.html'
    extra_context={'dataUrl': reverse_lazy('url-name')}
  ),
  name='sales.channel.bar'
),
```

That being said, you can simply use the [**`{% url … %}`** template tag [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url) in the JavaScript part, something like:

```
<script>
var dataUrl = "{% url 'url-name' %}";
<!--  …  -->
</script>
```

Comment: I myself would consider rendering into JavaScript an anti-pattern (might try a pull request on your repo some day) ;). A better way would be to render the url on some html tag as a data-attribute and get it from there.